# How does ember data access fixtures declared with ic-ajax's declareFixture?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ic-ajax

I am attempting to use `ember-cli` and `ember-cli-ic-ajax` for Ember Data fixtures. I have imported `ic.ajax.defineFixture` as `icDefineFixture`.

```
icDefineFixture('/users', {
  response: {
    email: 'user@example.com'
  },
  textStatus: 'success',
  jqXHR: {}
});
```

Which doesn't throw any errors, so I know I'm importing the function successfully. I then create a record, which goes okay:

```
this.store.createRecord('user', {});
```

But when I try and save it in a controller action:

```
this.get('model').save().then(function() { ... });
```

I get 404 errors because ember data is contacting my server which doesn't have a backend when I'm testing.

I'm puzzled how Ember Data is supposed to know to use ic-ajax's ajax methods. Is this something I must manually set up? I haven't managed to find any documentation on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ToddSmithSalter for the suggestion which led me to a solution that turned out to work very well for my case. I was able to simply reopen my adapter in a file that's only loaded in my test suite and override the ajax method:

```
ApplicationAdapter.reopen({
  ajax: function(url, verb, hash) {
    icRequest(url)
  }
});
```

Where I have imported `ic.ajax.request` as `icRequest`

This seems to work fine, but I don't see a way to register fixtures separately for each type of request `PUT`, `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that ember-data uses ic-ajax at all, but jQuery.ajax. In the app I'm currently writing, I'm using ic-ajax instead of $.ajax, simply because it returns RSVP promises. Now, I'm making requests without ember-data.

Here's an example from the Ghost source where ic-ajax has been used to make requests.

Setup: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/client/utils/ajax.js
Usage: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/client/controllers/setup.js#L23

Regarding fixtures, from the ic-ajax Github readme:

> Adding fixtures with defineFixture tells ic-ajax to resolve the promise with the fixture matching a url instead of making a request. This allows you to test your app without creating fake servers with sinon, etc.

```
Example:

ic.ajax.defineFixture('api/v1/courses', {
  response: [{name: 'basket weaving'}],
  jqXHR: {},
  textStatus: 'success'
});

ic.ajax.request('api/v1/courses').then(function(result) {
  deepEqual(result, ic.ajax.lookupFixture('api/v1/courses').response);
});
```

Now, if you want to use ic-ajax with ember-data, you *could* override the createRecord, deleteRecord methods on the Adapter you're using. See this Ember API document about createRecord for an example of how ember-data makes ajax calls: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_createRecord

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It led me to a very simple way to get what I want working without overriding all the various createRecord, find, etc. I just override the adapter's ajax method and all is well.

Comment: Good call. Glad you got it figured.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kevin-bullaughey comment I was able to adjust the solution for  Ember CLI 0.2.0-beta.1:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

import ENV from '../config/environment';
import { request } from 'ic-ajax';

var ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();

if (ENV.environment === "test") {
    ApplicationAdapter.reopen({
        ajax: function(url) {
            return request(url);
        }
    });
}

export default ApplicationAdapter;
```

In the `test` environment the adapter will use the defined `ic-ajax` fixtures and behave unchanged in `development` or `production`.

Comment: __request__ is default, so no need for braces in import.